# Display Order Details using Increment Id

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I've created a module to track orders, But the order details such as ( Product Name, Image, Size, Color, Quantity) are not displaying in the result page.

I'm getting the shipping address and Price of the product

**Code**

```
<?php $order = Mage::registry('current_order');?>
<?php
    $OrderNumber = $order->getIncrementId();
        $getOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($OrderNumber);
        $getOrder->getAllVisibleItems();
        $orderItems = $getOrder->getItemsCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
        ->load();

    ?>
    <?php
        $order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
        $order_id = $OrderNumber;
        $order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $payment_method = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
        $formattedPriceSubtotal = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getSubtotal(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceShipping = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getShippingAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceDiscount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getDiscountAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceTax = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getTaxAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceGrandtotal = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getGrandTotal(), true, false);
        $_shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

        foreach($orderItems as $sItem) {
            if($sItem->getProductType() == "simple")
            {
                $orderIdArray[$orderCount] = $this->escapeHtml($this->getIncrementId());
               // code for size and color
                $Get_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
                $productSize = $Get_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($Get_product);
                $productColor =  $Get_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($Get_product);
                $pItemId = $sItem->getParentItemId();

                $item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load("$pItemId");

                $qty = intval($item->getQtyOrdered());


    //get Active Product Data
    $nProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
    $nSku = $nProduct->getSku();


    $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $Parent_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','product-sku');
    $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($Parent_product->getPrice(), true, false);
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**$OrderNumber** give order `increment id not order id`  that

Use `loadByIncrementId()` instead of `load()`.

```
 $getOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderNumber);
```

You done lot of code,**Several time load product model/order object,you need to optimized:**

```
<?php
        $OrderNumber = $order->getIncrementId();
        $getOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderNumber);
        $orderItems= $getOrder->getAllVisibleItems();


        $payment_method = $getOrder->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
        $formattedPriceSubtotal = Mage::helper('core')->currency($getOrder->getSubtotal(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceShipping = Mage::helper('core')->currency($getOrder->getShippingAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceDiscount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($getOrder->getDiscountAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceTax = Mage::helper('core')->currency($getOrder->getTaxAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceGrandtotal = Mage::helper('core')->currency($getOrder->getGrandTotal(), true, false);
        $_shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

        foreach($orderItems as $sItem) {
                $Get_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
                $productSize = $Get_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($Get_product);
                $productColor =  $Get_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($Get_product);
                $qty = intval($sItem->getQtyOrdered()); // order qty 
                $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($Get_product->getPrice(), true, false);


        }
?>
```

Comment: After adding this I'm getting **Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on a non-object**

Comment: change `$Parent_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','product-sku');` to `$Parent_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$nSku )\;`

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
<?php $order = Mage::registry('current_order');?>
<?php
    $OrderNumber = $order->getIncrementId();
        $getOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($OrderNumber)
        $getOrder->getAllVisibleItems();
        $orderItems = $getOrder->getItemsCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
        ->load();


        //$order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
        //$order_id = $OrderNumber;
        //$order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $payment_method = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
        $formattedPriceSubtotal = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getSubtotal(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceShipping = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getShippingAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceDiscount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getDiscountAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceTax = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getTaxAmount(), true, false);
        $formattedPriceGrandtotal = Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getGrandTotal(), true, false);
        $_shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

        foreach($orderItems as $sItem) {
            if($sItem->getProductType() == "simple")
            {
                $orderIdArray[$orderCount] = $this->escapeHtml($this->getIncrementId());
               // code for size and color
                $Get_product= Mage::Model('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
                $productSize = $Get_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($Get_product);
                $productColor =  $Get_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($Get_product);
                $pItemId = $sItem->getParentItemId();

                $item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load("$pItemId");

                $qty = intval($item->getQtyOrdered());


    //get Active Product Data
    $nProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
    $nSku = $nProduct->getSku();


    $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $Parent_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','product-sku');
    $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($Parent_product->getPrice(), true, false);
?>
```

Comment: It didn't worked

Comment: check updated answer