# Get Customer's First Order increment Id

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer-account

**Background** :

I can able to download excel sheet with information of customer's Id , name....

[image]

**Requirement** :

How to get Customer's First Order id in excel ?

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}
// Only for urls // Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init();
    Mage::app();   
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
ini_set('memory_limit','500M');
$customerCount = 0;
try{
    //configure the collection filters.
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname');   

    //Add a page size to the result set.
    $collection->setPageSize(50);
    //discover how many page the result will be.
    $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
    $currentPage = 1;
    //This is the file to append the output to.
    $fp = fopen('customers.csv', 'w');
    $addedKeys = false;
    do{
         //Tell the collection which page to load.
         $collection->setCurPage($currentPage);
         $collection->load();
         foreach ($collection as $customer){
            //write the collection array as a CSV.
            $customerArray = $customer->toArray();
            $customerREquiredArray['customer ID'] = $customerArray['entity_id'];
            $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];

            if($addedKeys == false){
                $keys = array_keys($customerREquiredArray);
                fputcsv($fp, $keys);
                $addedKeys = true;
            }
            //var_dump($customerArray); echo "\n\n";
            fputcsv($fp, $customerREquiredArray);
            //fwrite($fp,print_r($customerArray,true) . chr(10) );
            $customerCount++;
         }
         $currentPage++;
         //make the collection unload the data in memory so it will pick up the next page when load() is called.
         $collection->clear();
         //break; //DEBUG
         echo "Finished page $currentPage of $pages \n"; 
    } while ($currentPage <= $pages);
    fclose($fp);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //$response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    Mage::printException($e);
}
echo "Saved $customerCount customers to csv file \n";
```

Comment: Maybe this will help (in Database it call increment_id)
Try this [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112457/display-order-details-using-increment-id)

Comment: @Marcel Thanks for the link, but i need to fetch order id based on customer id....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get first customer id with following code

```
foreach ($collection as $customer){
   $newordercollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerArray['entity_id']);

  $collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');
  $firstItem = $newordercollection->getFirstItem();
  $orderID = $firtItem->getIncrementId();
  $customerArray = $customer->toArray();
        $customerREquiredArray['customer ID'] = $customerArray['entity_id'];
        $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];
       $customerREquiredArray['First Order'] = $orderID;

        if($addedKeys == false){
            $keys = array_keys($customerREquiredArray);
            fputcsv($fp, $keys);
            $addedKeys = true;
        }
        //var_dump($customerArray); echo "\n\n";
        fputcsv($fp, $customerREquiredArray);
        //fwrite($fp,print_r($customerArray,true) . chr(10) );
        $customerCount++;

}
```

Comment: @BabyinMagento update the code.

Comment: yes, its displaying last 3 digits in order id, please help me for complete `order id`.....

Comment: example : instead of `100000122` , its displaying `122` only....

Comment: here is full code : https://pastebin.com/AqeL5gpL

Comment: @BabyinMagento updated the code..